# Generar consultas en shopify y almacenarlas en MySQL desde otro hosting

Tags: php, base-de-datos

Tengo una tienda en linea en `shopify`, quisiera usar el siguiente código `php` para insertar datos en una base de datos en otro hosting.

Específicamente quiero guardar los correos de los visitantes que se registren a un formulario.

```
<?php
    $conexion = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "password", "database");

    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $sql = "INSERT into suscriptores (suscriptor) VALUES('$email')";
    $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
?>
```

Me gustaria saber si es posible que los correos que se registren en el formulario que yo tengo en la página web en shopify pueden llegar a una base de datos alojada en otro hosting.

Tengo inseguridad debido al tipo de plataforma que es shopify que no me permita enviar los datos que yo quiero guardar a esa base de datos externa.
Gracias :)

Comment: Por favor amplia la pregunta especificando cual es el problema que estas teniendo e indicando los errores puntuales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacer una conexión a un servidor remoto podrías hacer algo así:

```
$db_host        = 'PON.TU.DIRECCION.IP';
$db_user        = 'user';
$db_pass        = 'password';
$db_database    = 'database'; 
$db_port        = '3306';

$conexion = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_database,$db_port);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shopify es una plataforma ofrecida en la modalidad "as a service", es decir, que la gestión del software que se ejecuta ahí es hecha por la gente de shopify (a menos que tengas Shopify Plus), el propietario de la tienda solo puede hacer algunos ajustes a la parte visual de la misma (yo me imagino que eso ya lo sabías), en tu caso si lo que tienes es un formulario en la tienda y estás capturando datos de los clientes (o los potenciales clientes) por ahí, estos datos se registrarán directamente en el sistema shopify (de tu tienda), para poder llevar esa información a otro sistema (un segundo sistema) te toca trabajar con el API Rest de shopify o con el sistema de notificaciones basado en webhooks, como capturas los datos? Puedes seguir una de las dos siguientes estrategias:

1. Definir un webhook en tu tienda (aquí dice como: https://help.shopify.com/manual/sell-online/notifications/webhooks) que se active cuando un nuevo usuario se registra en la tienda, que debería ser cuando el formulario que has mencionado recibe un nuevo cliente.
2. Programar todo en tu servidor alterno (el que va a correr el script php) para que invoque el endpoint de "customers" de tu tienda en shopify (Acá se describen los métodos disponibles: https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/customer) para que un script php a través de una tarea programada en el servidor (alterno, no en shopify) verifique cada X tiempo por nuevos usuarios registrados en la tienda y los registre en tu DB mysql.

Espero sea util.